# My API stops working as soon as I fix the react "cannont GET /route" error

Tags: node.js, express, .htaccess

I have this React web with its API working perfectly fine on my local. When migrating to an Apache server I got the typical "cannot GET /dashboard" error, so I added this lines to my .htaccess and all routes work fine, great.

```
RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.html [L]
```

and now, all my routes work fine

```
mydomain.com/dashboard
mydomain.com/games
mydomain.com/best-players
```

The thing is that after fixing this, my API endpoints (Node/Express and located in **mydomain.com/API** folder) stop working as obviously my .htaccess is affecting them and after trying several examples I found online I'm not being able to make both things work properly. For example, the endpoint **mydomain.com/api/top10** is not returning any result, just trying to render like if it was a component/route.

Then I added a line to filter the api folder, so now my .htaccess is like:

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^(api)($|/) - [L]
RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.html [L]
```

Still, same result, all I get is a html with

```
<noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
```

Also, as extra info I didn´t mention, if I delete that .htaccess file, my API works fine, it returns all the info it should return... but the actual website it doesnt work (due to React router).

What's the best approach I should follow? I guess I can fix it with some extra lines in my .htaccess to handle the API calls but I'm not being able to do it.

Comment: You should not assume that everyone knows by heart what routes the React framework uses. Instead you should transparently name the routes in the question so that the issue gets reduced to what you say it is: a rewriting task on protocol level. That makes answering your question much more straight forward.

Comment: The first RewriteRule already prevents further rewriting, when the index.html gets requested. Add a second one, that does the same thing, when the requested path starts with `API/`.

Comment: Done @arkascha, I´m sorry about that, I didn´t think it was neccesary at all.

Comment: I think that´s exactly what I was editing @CBroe while you posted this comment.

Comment: What does make URLs like `/api/top10` "work" to begin with in your setup? Is there a separate .htaccess inside the `/api/` folder?

Comment: You mean what it returns? Well, a  json with the best players for a game... it works fine on localhost and also on my server if I delete the htaccess (but then the actual website stops working, I can´t have both the web and the api working at the same time)

And no, I don´t have any other .htaccess in the API folder, just the one in the root @CBroe

Comment: No, I mean how the routing for that works. `/api/top10` is not going to match a physically existing file of that name in that folder, I would assume?

Comment: No no, in the /api folder there´s just an app.js file with all the routes and express stuff

Comment: Usually I'm not using htaccess for this. I rather implement a (bottom most) fallback route with express that forwards everything that the API should not handle to index.html

Comment: Also added that to my app.js and restarted but still not working... __dirname if the app.js directory? Because it´s in nodejs/api folder, so probably I should go up two levels... at the moment I have it like this @devnull69 (awesome nickname)

app.get("/*", function(req, res) {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "index.html"));
});